# How this template works in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

How this template works, can any body explain?

```
<xsl:template match="/*"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can read about it [here](http://www.xmlmaster.org/en/article/d01/c08/)

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, there are [seven kinds of nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp): element, attribute, text, namespace, processing-instruction, comment, and document nodes.

`/` is the root node. The root node is a [document node](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_nodes.asp): it contains the entire document.

`*` matches [all children of that node](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp). In most XML documents, there is only one child: the root element.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start> - this is the root element
  <two - node on second level>
  <three - node on second level>
      <four - node on third level/>
  </three>
</start>
```

so it would match element node `start`.

Comment: "match="/*" matches all nodes (*) that are children of the root node (/)" is not quite correct as it matches all child *elements* of the root node (and in most cases, assuming an XML document as the input where any XML document has exactly one root element), meaning it matches the root element. There could also be comment or processing instruction children of the root node which `match="/*"` does not match. Your example astonishes me, is that meant as an example for the text? The `one` element is the child element of the root node so the template matches that element, not the ones you name.

Comment: I don't see how that update makes any more sense, in the sample XML the path or pattern `/*` selects or matches the element `rootnode` and not its children. The `/` itself which you have mentioned in the text as the root node is not the same as the root element. You can't see the root node in the lexical markup sample but in the data model it is a container node of type document node that has the `rootnode` element as its child.

Comment: Fixed. I've been working with XML for several years now and never realized that / does not refer to the root element.